# Calendar dateobject performance issues

Tags: views, caching, datetime

I am using Drupal 7 and unfortunately there are problems with the calendar module. The calendar itself is used in a relatively small enviroment of 20-40 users, which are all registered userers with permanent accounts.
The problem is the more appointments I add to the calendar, the slower the whole
calendar gets. It seems the problem is related to the dateobject, which can be seen in the following screenshot, which displays the parsing between the objects:

[image: Parsing]

I don't know why there are like 15k calls, if I roughly have 50-300 appointments.

Does anyone know this problem or has suggestions how to solve it? I also tried to cache the calendar, but that does not work at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment:

I just figured out the problem lies within repeating dates. If I for example create a Date that repeats itself each week on monday 100 times Drupal always loads ALL of these events, even though there is just 1 of 100 of these events, in the month my view currenly shows.

Maybe someone knows a way to change that, so it just loads the dates which occur in my current instance of the view?

Please help.

As demanded a full view:

[image]

I defnitely cornered the problem on the reapeating events in my calendar. If I reduce them, the latency is fine.

Comment: Can you provide a full view of the cachegrind, or link to the cachegrind file?

Comment: I have done as you asked.